# How to get actual time a document in a SharePoint library was modified

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to read the contents of a SharePoint library and get the metadata of the files.

Every item in a SharePoint library has a created time and a modified time.

Is is possible to get the actual time a document was modified before it was uploaded to a library?
Or can I get only the modified time of the library item?

p.s. I am using a SPO site in a tenant; I am only a site admin

Answer (score 0):

The time shown by the modified field, is the actual time the file that is stored in SharePoint was modified. As for the time the file was modified on the a user's machine, you'll most likely need to check a local copy of the file/have access to their machine.

Most users open the file from SharePoint and their changes are synchronised with SharePoint, so the modified time is accurate (in terms of when the desktop application saved the file and synchronised those changes with SharePoint).

Comment: My requirement is to automatically re-upload files in the library, if the source files were modified after being uploaded here.

Comment: Have you considered just using the sync functionality?

Comment: I need to get the files from a webservice

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Aren't the source files on a user's machine? or are they being modified elsewhere? If they're on a Windows machine then the source files can be kept in sync using the OneDrive app (SharePoint library sync).

Comment: I need to get the files from a webservice, and if they are newer than the files in the library, then upload them

Comment: This seems like a problem relating to your web service and not SharePoint. SharePoint's modified date is accurate, so as long as you can retrieve the time your file was last modified from the web service, there should be no problem. Files modified on Windows have date modified in the file metadata but we have no idea what underlying OS your web service is using.

Comment: My question was to know if the actual modified date in the file metadata can still be accessed when the file is in the library. It looks like I will be able to get only the SharePoint modified date at this point; I will have to look for alternative approaches.

Comment: In your earlier comment, you said you only upload the files to the library if they are newer than the existing files in the library. Surely by the point the file has been uploaded to SharePoint, you have already checked the modified date from either the file or web service?

Comment: I said 'I need to get files and upload if newer'. so that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to check with your web service or the source files whether they have a newer modified date than the modified date returned by SharePoint and then decide whether to update the files in SharePoint with your source files.

Answer (score 0):

"Is is possible to get the actual time a document was modified before it was uploaded to a library"
Yes and no.

In many cases there will be a difference between the actual time the file was modified and when it was uploaded to SharePoint.

Quite a few file formats contain the creation and modified date in the file itself. For example, in Word click "File" | "Info" to see the actual date the Word file was created and last modified.
Which file formats use this mechanism? docx, xlsx, pptx, vsdx, pdf, jpg, dwg, audio and video files. For msg and eml you may want to use the sent date as the modified date.

File formats without dates are txt, zip, gif, ...

Basically, if the modified dates from SharePoint are good enough use them. If not, you will need to look for 3rd party tools that offer this capability.

Paul | SLIM Applications